# Merge [apple-app-site-associate] and [apple-app-site-association]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's currently 45 questions for [apple-app-site-associate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-app-site-associate), and 16 for [apple-app-site-association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-app-site-association). This is about the JSON file that's used to provide iOS deep links and App Clips. However, the correct filename should be "apple-app-site-association", which is referenced in many parts of the documentation:

["Support Universal Links"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

> Create an **apple-app-site-association** file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle.

["Supporting Associated Domains"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains)

> To associate a website with your app, you’ll need to have the associated domain file on your website and the appropriate entitlement in your app. The apps in the **apple-app-site-association** file on your website must have a matching Associated Domains Entitlement.

["Associated Domains Entitlement"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains)

> In macOS 11 and later and iOS 14 and later, apps request **apple-app-site-association** files from an Apple-managed content delivery network (CDN) dedicated to associated domains, instead of directly from your web server.

Even the tag description of [apple-app-site-associate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-app-site-associate) says

> Allows websites opened within an iOS browser to redirect to a native app, by adding a **apple-app-site-association** file to the root of the website.

... but the correct tag has much less questions, and no description at all. Merge them?